# Code change monitoring malfunctioning with Django 1.7 on mod-wsgi

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

This is an issue that I've encountered on all my sites that are running Django 1.7 in mod_wsgi.  The nub of the issue is that if, while developing locally, I introduce a fatal error into the codebase, and then subsequently correct it, the code monitoring script doesn't detect the correction.

I use [Graham Dumpleton's monitor.py script](http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2008/12/using-modwsgi-when-developing-django.html) to detect changes to the codebase when I'm developing locally (I use apache rather than the Django development server).

It always used to work in Django <= 1.6, but in Django 1.7 I get the following error:

```
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
    django.setup()
File "/home/me/virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 21, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
File "/home/me/.virtualenvs/myvirtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

The irritating thing is that if I correct the error, monitor.py doesn't detect the change, so I have to either restart apache, or touch another file that was already loaded (e.g. the settings file).

I think this is because of the fact that "the reloading code only monitors imported files (aka sys.modules)" ([source](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22729#comment:3)).  So because the incorrect file wasn't successfully imported, monitor.py doesn't know to restart the process.

Comment: This is similar to how the python interactive interpreter cannot live reload perfectly. There is a copy of the code in the memory anyways and in many cases deleting the `.pyc/.pyo` files don't work. We fixed this error by putting a watcher on all files and reloading the apache entry point (`wsgi`) on change. This has a slight lag, and you can switch it off for production.

Comment: something similar happened to me using uwsgi. I then started using need-app=true. This makes uwsgi discard the app because it is not correctly loading. So once you develop the new change it will work. Maybe you can find something similar.

Comment: I've ended up switching to the Django development server for local development.  Unless you've got a really good reason, I'd say it's a much better approach than working with Apache & mod_wsgi for local Django development.

Comment: Is there a question here? I can see a complaint :-) but not a question that would have a correct answer. On the other hand, if you *do* have an answer, please provide that as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your deployment process is nor your production operating system, but in the Linux/Ubuntu world there is a OS command called pyclean.  During my Django/Python deployment scripts (usually via fabric) I issue the command "pyclean ." in the project root.  This script recursively deletes all .pyc files starting in the current folder.  I hope this helps.