# Django populate() isn't reentrant

Tags: python, django, apache

I keep getting this when I try to load my Django application on production      . I tried all the stackoverflow answers but nothing has fixed it. Any other ideas. (I'm using Django 1.5.2 and Apache)

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "/var/www/thehomeboard/wwwhome/wsgi.py", line 37, in <module>
           application = get_wsgi_application()
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
           django.setup()
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
           apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
         File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
           raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
       RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: How are you running Django? Do you see any other errors anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean by how am I running django? I get the errors in the apache log files only.

Comment: What are you using to run the actual wsgi application? mod_wsgi? This error is caused either by an error during `populate()`, in which case this is the error you get the next time it is run, or, less likely, by improperly run asynchronous code - for example when using gevent without the proper configuration.

Comment: yes I'm using mod_wsgi

Comment: When I removed all the non-django apps from INSTALLED_APPS I get other problems but the 'populate() isn't reentrant' is no longer there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the end the problem that I had was that I tried to run a second Django app and did not have the following defined in my apache config:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess ...
WSGIProcessGroup ...
```

Just learned that you can run a single django app without defining them but when its two it produces a conflict.

Comment: This also happened to me today, when I accidentally deployed my Django project developed for Python 2.x to a Python 3.x instance on Webfaction. I did not investigate the details. Just something to check before going down the rabbit hole.

Answer (score 36):

This RuntimeError first occured for me after upgrading to Django 1.7 (and still is present with Django 1.8). It is usually caused by an Django application which raises an error, but that error is swallowed somehow.

Here's a workaround which works for me. Add it to your wsgi.py and the *real* error should be logged:

```
import os
import time
import traceback
import signal
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

try:
    application = get_wsgi_application()
    print 'WSGI without exception'
except Exception:
    print 'handling WSGI exception'
    # Error loading applications
    if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules:
        traceback.print_exc()
        os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)
        time.sleep(2.5)
```

See [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/X3Upsk9Wfsw) on modwsgi for more details.

Comment: This just keeps giving me an error that says `Target WSGI script '/home/admusr/project/WebManager/wsgi.py' does not contain WSGI application 'application'.`

Comment: Using this solution - I get "NameError: global name 'sys' is not defined" as this snippet is lacking an "import sys"

Comment: The above code is not the full wsgi.py file. You should have an `import sys` somewhere on top of the default file already. If not, add it.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for me to find actual issue. -:)

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you.

Comment: This answer but with `if 'mod_wsgi' in sys.modules` removed helped me solve the issue using the Django dev server. Thanks.

Comment: life saver...this trick eventually reveal the real issue location.

Answer (score 4):

There will be many reason to causes to `populate() isn't reentrant` error. If you look at the `registry.py` in your in django application probably inside this directory
 `/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps`

```
        # app_config should be pristine, otherwise the code below won't
        # guarantee that the order matches the order in INSTALLED_APPS.
        if self.app_configs:
            raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
```

As you see in the comment it says app_config should be pristine. Which means if one of configuration is not correct or required library missing it will rise this populate error. I got this error because I have missed sqlite installation. Even as you see there is no mentioning possible causes in the exception. I installed sqlite by this command on debian

```
pip install pysqlite
```

It solved my problem. My exception because of missing pysqlite.Your maybe having missing of another required packages or errors in your `settings.py`

Answer (score 3):

For those using **AWS Lambda** (and optionally using zappa) this can happen when the size of code & dependencies zipped into a deployment package exceeds 250MB after decompression.

Typically the zip may only be 50 MB but may decompress to over 250MB so you may need to manually unzip the deployment package to check it isn't too large when uncompressed.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html

Answer (score 2):

Full disclosure - "populate() isn't reentrant" errors can have multiple causes, and checking any recent config or program changes is a very good idea.

However, this error can also occur when Apache is updated, and a module is no longer valid/is corrupted/needs refreshing.  This occurred to us on Webfaction after an Apache update (but may happen on any host).

Using the Apache restart script will NOT help this, because the modules remain loaded on the restart.  Depending on your system, and whether the mods are cached even when Apache is shut down, this may help.

Fully stop Apache.  On Webfaction, that is:

```
~/webapps/<YOUR WEB APP>/apache2/bin/stop
```

Wait a few seconds, and then...

```
~/webapps/<YOUR WEB APP>/apache2/bin/start
```

That should correct the issue.  If your system caches the mods, you may have to flush the cache before starting.

Hope this helps!

Here is the link they gave me (I know the error is different, but we had this happen for the same reason with the populate error as well):

https://statusblog.webfaction.com/2018/05/16/regarding-glibc_private-errors-in-your-python-application/

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was caused, because I hadn't correctly split my `INSTALLED_APPS` for local and production. Meaning in local I was using `django-cors-headers` and in production I was not. But I accidentally had left `django-cors-headers` even though I removed it from my production `requirements.txt`. After delete `cors-headers` from the installed apps in production the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I got it, a lot of comments were about the problem that hidden, means

> populate() isn't reentrant

is not a original problem.
In my case, I have changed the password in my local DB for main user and I forget to change DB setting in another project.