# Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/github/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: python, django, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying for two days to deploy my django project on aws. But i am getting one error after another.
After lots of searching for answers. This is the last error that i am not able to overcome.

I am following these guides:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html
https://www.1strategy.com/blog/2017/05/23/tutorial-django-elastic-beanstalk/

After all of it.
When i try to access my site.It shows 500 Server Error.
In Logs it Shows

```
 Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/github/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

Another question on net answered to comment the Database lines in settings file.

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
}
}
```

This is my wsgi.py file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'myproject.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

After it my site loads. But then the problem is there is not database. So it throws another error

```
settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details.
```

So now i am struck here. I have looked at every related question tried there solution but nothing is working. It is my first time trying AWS and it is turning out to be very hard. I deployed my project on heroku successfully but heroku does not support cron job and i really need something like cron job for my project.

This is my django.config in .ebextensions folder

```
    option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "github.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "github/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []
```

After changing to WSGIPath: github.wsgi:application

The error stays the same as 500 internal error
but error in log changes so.

```
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625700 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625707 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625711 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625721 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625725 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625730 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625734 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     app_config.import_models()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625740 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625743 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625749 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625753 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625758 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625776 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625782 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
665, in _load_unlocked
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625816 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625832 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625838 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 206, in contribute_to_class-- More  --[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625859 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625884 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     check_sqlite_version()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:46.625889 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 67, in check_sqlite_version-- M[Fri Sep 18 19:50:47.629796 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:47.629840 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:47.629850 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:47.629860 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:47.629884 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:48.633315 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:48.633351 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:48.633362 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:48.633372 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:48.633396 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:28] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:49.638585 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:32] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:49.638628 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:32]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:49.638638 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:32]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:49.638647 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:32]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Sep 18 19:50:49.638672 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 127.0.0.1:32] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:21.223059 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:21.223107 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:21.223118 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:21.223154 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:22.482909 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:22.482955 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:22.482966 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Fri Sep 18 19:51:22.483001 2020] [:error] [pid 6504] [remote 172.31.2.91:32] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Do you have `.ebextensions/django.config` file? If so, could you post it here?

Comment: `option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment":
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "github.settings"
    PYTHONPATH: "$PYTHONPATH"
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: "github/wsgi.py"
    StaticFiles: "/static/=www/static/"

packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []
`

Comment: Change WSGIPath: `WSGIPath: github.wsgi:application`
`

Comment: Did that but it still shows 500 internal server error

Comment: Please run `python manage.py check`

Comment: it returns System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

Comment: Ok, actually the error you see now might be caused by many reasons. I suggest you to try this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/30968197/764182 to detect real problem. Maybe it's missing package