# Django app deployment in AWS Beanstalk - Error after deployment - Internal Server Error

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I have a django app deployed to AWS beanstalk. The first version was fine after following the official documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

Then, I added a new feature using django-filter to my site. Now, when I deploy, I get this error on the main front end page:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Below is the error log I have.

````
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:09.118698 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.47.200:20528]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:09.118704 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.47.200:20528]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:09.118707 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.47.200:20528]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:09.118722 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.47.200:20528] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477606 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477658 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477768 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477801 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]   File "/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477806 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477812 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477816 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477822 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477825 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477831 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477834 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:13.477849 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.3.100:48] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516356 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516412 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516522 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516557 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]   File "/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516562 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516568 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516572 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516577 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516589 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516596 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516599 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:17.516615 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.29.143:48] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.842837 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.842888 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44] mod_wsgi (pid=21279): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843064 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843099 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]   File "/opt/python/current/app/djangoproject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843103 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843110 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843113 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843119 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843123 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843129 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843132 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Oct 01 04:47:18.843147 2020] [:error] [pid 21279] [remote 172.31.58.190:44] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant ```
````

These are my requirements.txt:

```
asgiref==3.2.10
Django==3.1.1
django-ckeditor==6.0.0
django-filter==2.3.0
django-js-asset==1.2.2
PyJWT==1.7.1
pytz==2020.1
sqlparse==0.3.1
```

WSGI File:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: djangoproject/wsgi.py
```

Could you please help. Have been trying to fix this for a while now.

Thank you so much,
Cj

Comment: Adding more of todays code:

Comment: There are other issues regarding your errors, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954398/django-populate-isnt-reentrant?lq=1) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant). Have you explored any of them, and why they don't work in your case?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Yes I have tried them both. In the first one I have all dependencies and it shows up correctly in requirements.. for second one I tried the registry bit as well but the same error shows up. Any suggestions?

Comment: Anything I can try

Comment: Can you ssh into the EB instance and inspect from there? Manually try launching it and see if you get any errors. Thus could help identifying why automation fails.

Comment: Facing this problem as well. Everything was working fine and next deployment this!

Answer (score 0):

Do this in your `.ebextensions` django config file:

```
command: "source /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/activate && pip install -r requirements/production.txt"
```

So basically activate the venv and run pip install makes sure dependencies are installed in the right venv. Also:

```
aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
 WSGIPath: config.wsgi:application
```

In my case I have a config folder in the root in which `wsgi.py` file exists

Comment: Thank you both. I have the wsgi bit but no luck. I will try once again with both and come back here