# ImportError: No module named 'sysmon'

Tags: python, django, importerror

This is my first release of a new Django app on my production server.  Locally it works perfectly but on my production server I get the following 500 Internal Error. I can't figure out what sysmon referees too.

from my log file:

```
    [Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415601 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480] mod_wsgi (pid=6066): Target WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415680 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480] mod_wsgi (pid=6066): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415717 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415869 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module>
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415883 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415971 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.415978 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     django.setup()
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416060 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416067 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416220 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416227 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416341 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416348 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     module = import_module(entry)
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416455 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/importlib/__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416462 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416479 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416494 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416508 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2224, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Thu Jun 25 06:49:11.416615 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229352871680] [remote 127.0.0.1:52480] ImportError: No module named 'sysmon'
```

And also I've just notice that when restart the server I get the following error (RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
):

```
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556475 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=6066): Target WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556561 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=6066): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556611 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556685 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module>
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556695 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556748 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556757 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     django.setup()
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556799 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556818 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556861 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556870 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.556903 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6066:tid 140229247973120] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846673 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172] mod_wsgi (pid=6067): Target WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846748 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172] mod_wsgi (pid=6067): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py'.
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846787 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846843 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/src/hoozdis/wsgi.py", line 31, in <module>
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846850 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846881 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846888 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]     django.setup()
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846914 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846920 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846946 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]   File "/home/ymorin007/webapps/hoozdis_com/lib/python3.4/Django-1.8.2-py3.4.egg/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846952 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Thu Jun 25 08:01:43.846973 2015] [wsgi:error] [pid 6067:tid 140229178517248] [remote 127.0.0.1:172] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: does the `sysmon` library/package need to be installed??

Comment: The initial setup of Django is in more recent Django versions no longer stateless. If an error occurs during the initial load, as is occurring because of your sysmon module issue, the subsequent attempts to reinitialise Django in the same process will fail. This is what the populate() isn't reentrant error is about. Fix that sysmon issue and the other will go away.

Answer (score 0):

> Frozen modules are modules written in Python whose compiled byte-code
>   object is incorporated into a custom-built Python interpreter by
>   Python’s freeze utility. See Tools/freeze/ for now.

From https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.init_frozen

It looks like somewhere someone's freezing some python code and not including all the necessary bits?   It's a little tricky to diagnose after that.  Try looking for something called sysmon locally.

Comment: When I restart the server I get RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant or https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/modwsgi/X3Upsk9Wfsw or https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas/issues/192