# RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant in Django

Tags: django, apache, python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to deploy django website.Project name is pom.
I am trying to run django website in ec2 server using apache2 and getting the following error:

Apache error file:

```
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:33.621285 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024755709824] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Attach interpreter ''.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:33.621462 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024755709824] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Adding '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/edusamosa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/' to path.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.145762 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20448:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.145888 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20448:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.145947 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20448:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11934] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.145953 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20448:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11934] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.152795 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Create interpreter 'www.edusamosa.in|'.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.153592 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Adding '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/edusamosa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/' to path.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.152795 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Create interpreter 'www.edusamosa.in|'.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.153592 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Adding '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/edusamosa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/' to path.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.153884 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213] mod_wsgi (pid=20446, process='pom', application='www.edusamosa.in|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354165 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354189 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354222 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354238 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354362 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     application = get_wsgi_application()
@                   [Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354238 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354362 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354377 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354416 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     django.setup()
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354428 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354465 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354476 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 85, in populate
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354590 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354602 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354590 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354602 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 86, in create
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354697 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     module = import_module(entry)
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354708 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354765 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213]     __import__(name)
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:44.354793 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024564070144] [remote 49.248.57.164:51213] ImportError: No module named allauth
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251341 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251496 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251559 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
         [Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251496 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251559 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
[Fri Jul 24 12:37:45.251565 2015] [authz_core:debug] [pid 20447:tid 140024656201472] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 49.248.57.164:11938] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://edusamosa.in/
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.251722 2015] [:info] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] mod_wsgi (pid=20446, process='pom', application='www.edusamosa.in|'): Loading WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252817 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252831 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] mod_wsgi (pid=20446): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252850 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252870 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
                [Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252850 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252870 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252913 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252923 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 14, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252940 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]     django.setup()
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252948 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252961 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252969 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252981 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
@                              
                                   @        [Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252969 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252981 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Jul 24 18:07:45.252996 2015] [:error] [pid 20446:tid 140024648070912] [remote 49.248.57.164:58879] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
~
```

My pom.settings.py is as follow:

```
"""
Django settings for pom project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/



ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition
'''
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    # 'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
    # other finders..
    # 'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)
'''
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog',
    'ckeditor',
    'reviewandrating',
    'links',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.linkedin',
    'import_export',
    'haystack',
    'mathfilters',

)
# Ankur's Setting.py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
    'django.core.context_processors.debug',
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    'django.core.context_processors.i18n',
    'django.core.context_processors.media',
    'django.core.context_processors.static',
    'django.core.context_processors.tz',
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'allauth.account.context_processors.account',



)
SITE_ID = 3
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'links.UserProfile'
LOGIN_URL = '/'

SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'links.my_adapter.MyAdapter'

SOCIALACCOUNT_QUERY_EMAIL = True
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {
        'SCOPE': ['email'],
        'AUTH_PARAMS': {'auth_type': 'reauthenticate'},
        'METHOD': 'js_sdk',
        'VERIFIED_EMAIL': False
    },

    'google':
        {'SCOPE': ['profile', 'email'],
         'AUTH_PARAMS': {'access_type': 'online'}},
    'linkedin':
        {'SCOPE': ['r_emailaddress'],
         'PROFILE_FIELDS': ['id',
                           'first-name',
                            'last-name',
                            'email-address',
                            'picture-url',
                            'public-profile-url']}

}

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)
ROOT_URLCONF = 'pom.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['/home/ubuntu/pom/templates/'],  # This is where you add the template directory
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'allauth.account.context_processors.account',
                'allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount',
            ],
        },
    },
]
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pom.wsgi.application'
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.solr_backend.SolrEngine',
        'URL': 'http://localhost:8983/solr/',
        'TIMEOUT': 60 * 5,
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
        'BATCH_SIZE': 100,
        'EXCLUDED_INDEXES': ['thirdpartyapp.search_indexes.BarIndex'],
    }
}

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'hidden',
        'USER': 'ubuntu',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '',
    '/home/ubuntu/pom/static/img/',
    '/home/ubuntu/pom/static/css/',
    '/home/ubuntu/pom/static/js/',
)

# TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
# 'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     #django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
# )

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    # os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
    '/home/ubuntu/pom/templates/',

)
CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'default': {
        'toolbar': 'full',
        'height': 300,
        'width': 900,
    },
}

CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = "uploads/"

CKEDITOR_IMAGE_BACKEND = 'Pillow'

CKEDITOR_JQUERY_URL = '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/pom/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/ubuntu/pom/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

HAYSTACK_SIGNAL_PROCESSOR = 'haystack.signals.RealtimeSignalProcessor'
```

The wsgi.py file is as follows:

```
"""
WSGI config for pom project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
import sys
from os.path import abspath, dirname, join
#sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ubuntu/deploy/pom')
sys.path.insert(0, abspath(join(dirname(__file__), "../")))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "pom.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: using django 1.8.2 and python 2.7

Comment: Can you try restarting your apache service?

Comment: And the above apache error include error after the restart

Comment: Something's not right with your wsgi file. Apache seems to think that it's not valid therefore if won't call it properly `Target WSGI script '/home/ubuntu/pom/pom/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.`

Comment: I'll dig a bit more when I get back home but hopefully you'll be able to resolve it by then.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django stops working with RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant)

Answer (score 6):

The error messages clearly says:

```
ImportError: No module named allauth
```

The populate() not reentrant error is an error that occurs when mod_wsgi attempts to reload the WSGI script file, after the first error, and finds that Django was half initialised due to first error and so it gives up.

Fix the issue with allauth module not being found and the latter error should go away.

Comment: If you look at the times, the allauth error was hours before the poplate() isn't reentrant error

Comment: Which is entirely possible since Apache is multi process. That process may not have received requests in the interim and so was sitting there waiting to have the problem.