# Mysql not working with python 3.6 and django 1.9

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, django-1.9

I am trying to connect mysql db with django 1.9 and python version is 3.6. With database connection string I am getting the below error. If I comment out the database connection string the site is loading fine. Can anybody tell  what is wrong in this.

```
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287609 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570] mod_wsgi (pid=29791): Target WSGI script '/home/abhadran/test/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287675 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570] mod_wsgi (pid=29791): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/home/abhadran/test/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287705 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287740 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]   File "/home/abhadran/test/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py", line 20, in <module>
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287787 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.287798 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]   File "/home/abhadran/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.290733 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.290756 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]   File "/home/abhadran/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.290779 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.290790 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]   File "/home/abhadran/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.291738 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Wed Apr 05 07:01:08.291768 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 29791] [remote 173.1.101.95:52570] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

My pip freeze

```
Django==1.9.12
django-tastypie==0.13.3
mod-wsgi==4.5.15
mysql-connector-python==2.0.4
mysqlclient==1.3.10
PyMySQL==0.6
python-dateutil==2.6.0
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
requests==2.13.0
six==1.10.0
```

DB Settings we are using to try to connect to the Mysql

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'HOST': 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA',
        'NAME': 'ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ',
    'USER': 'YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY',
        'PASSWORD': 'XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'PORT': '3306',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': 'SET storage_engine=INNODB',
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you installed *three* separate mysql client libraries? Those are alternatives.

Comment: Nevertheless, we can't help unless you show your actual settings.

Comment: what settings is required, is it wsgi or virtual configuration settings

Comment: Well, since you claim it is the database setting that causes this, you should at least post that.

Comment: @DanielRoseman we have updated the question with DB Settings, Here, the same db settings are working with the Python2.7 Version and same code as well, But the Issue is happening with Python 3.X Version (3.5 & 3.6)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, this error means there is an error in the Django project somewhere. It could be hard to locate.

You can try multiple solutions like:
1. Restart Apache
2. Execute makemigrations and migrate Django commands
3. Modify your wsgi.py file so you can manage the exception

A little note, in the line `File "/home/abhadran/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py"` indicate that you're using Python 3.6 and not Python 3.5 as you mentioned in your description.

Python 3.6 is officially supported until Django 1.11, so you maybe must upgrade your Django version or downgrade your Python in your venv.

Related posts:
- [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant)
- [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954398/django-populate-isnt-reentrant)
- [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618364/python-django-populate-isnt-reentrant)
- [Post 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289137/runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant-on-centos-7-django-1-9-python3)
- [Post 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31611117/runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant-in-django)