# Django works fine on local host,but when using eb deploy and viewing it in the browser it comes up with a 500 error?

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Im not sure what i am, doing wrong, when on my Django app, I run the app locally and it works fine with Amazon RDS. But when I deploy(eb deploy) then use (eb open) it doesn't work. It comes up with a 500 error. Any ideas on how i could fix this? Thanks!

This is the error in the logs:

```
      [Fri Nov 18 11:08:32.441246 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:32.441251 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:32.441261 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:32.441274 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444202 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444225 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444239 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444254 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444279 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444287 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444300 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444306 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444315 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444320 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444329 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:08:33.444342 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 127.0.0.1:27580] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702445 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702472 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702489 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702506 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702530 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702538 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702551 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702557 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702566 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702572 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702582 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:09:06.702595 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190170 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190197 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190232 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190249 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190272 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190280 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190292 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190297 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190305 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190310 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190319 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:12:26.190331 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:29884] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986835 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986861 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986878 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986895 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986918 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986926 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986939 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986945 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986954 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986960 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986969 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:06.986982 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432736 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432761 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432777 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432794 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432821 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432829 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432853 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432859 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432868 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432873 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432883 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:13:32.432895 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671161 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671186 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671202 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671218 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671242 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671250 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671262 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671268 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671277 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671282 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671292 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:14:36.671304 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31932] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070645 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070671 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070687 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070705 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070729 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070737 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070749 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070755 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070773 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070779 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070788 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:15:39.070801 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:27580] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684829 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684853 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] mod_wsgi (pid=10749): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py'.
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684868 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684885 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/current/app/hhh/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684908 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684915 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684928 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     django.setup()
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684934 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684943 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684949 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684958 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Fri Nov 18 11:16:05.684970 2016] [:error] [pid 10749] [remote 172.31.40.17:31676] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Here is the WSGI file

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "hhh.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Comment: check the error log file

Comment: @FrédéricHenri here is the error log file any ideas what the error is and how i could solve it?

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant

Comment: @Alasdair i have uploaded the full error log now :)

Comment: You need to go back and find the very first error raised when the first request hits a process. The ``populate()`` error is a subsequent follow up error for later requests caused by Django not liking attempts to be initialised more than once in a process. So restart your Apache instance, then make a single request and see what the very first error is.

Comment: [Fri Nov 18 21:10:39.479664 2016] [:error] [pid 31846] [remote 172.31.40.17:24]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Fri Nov 18 21:10:39.479670 2016] [:error] [pid 31846] [remote 172.31.40.17:24]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate