# Trying to deploy Django in Windows, it seems to be impossible

Tags: python, django, windows, apache, deployment

Hello guys I hope you can help me I’m trying to deploy django 1.11 on a Window machine but it seems to be impossible, I already have apache and wsgi_mod installed correctly in the machine, actually when I setup a project it works fine, the 127.0.0.1 (localhost) show me the django welcome message correctly, I also can install correctly the application, the problem is when I add the application in settings.py it show me (500 Internal Server Error) my project works fine in a virtualenv, even this project was made in the same machine, I hope you can help me because this issue makes me crazy.

**httpd.conf**

```
DocumentRoot "C:\cotizaciones\proyecto"
<Directory "C:\cotizaciones\proyecto">
    #
    # Possible values for the Options directive are "None", "All",
    # or any combination of:
    #   Indexes Includes FollowSymLinks SymLinksifOwnerMatch ExecCGI MultiViews
    #
    # Note that "MultiViews" must be named *explicitly* --- "Options All"
    # doesn't give it to you.
    #
    # The Options directive is both complicated and important.  Please see
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options
    # for more information.
    #
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

    #
    # AllowOverride controls what directives may be placed in .htaccess files.
    # It can be "All", "None", or any combination of the keywords:
    #   Options FileInfo AuthConfig Limit
    #
    AllowOverride None

    #
    # Controls who can get stuff from this server.
    #
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<IfModule wsgi_module>

    WSGIScriptAlias / "C:\cotizaciones\proyecto\proyecto\wsgi.py"
    WSGIPythonPath "C:\cotizaciones\proyecto"

    <Directory "C:\cotizaciones\proyecto\proyecto">

    <Files wsgi.py>
        Allow from all    
    </Files>

   </Directory>

</IfModule>
```

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'aplicacion',
]
```

I will really apreciate a hand,
Thank you!

Comment: You need to show the errors from the Apache log.

Comment: if you set `DEBUG=True` in your settings you will see alot more info about your error (probably ...)

Comment: here is the error.log, thank you.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dR6GBDkTyG/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant might help ... there is also some threads from google about "populate isnt reentrant" ... this usually indicates an error in your apache config in my experience or your wsgi but it could easily be a problem with the python packages you have installed (or the version wsgi thinks is your default)

Comment: This is the erro log set in True. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/NrKxD9KSrW/