# AWS Django Multiple Errors in logs apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am new to AWS and cannot make sense of this error. I am using Django 2.1, python 3.6 and aws elasticbean stalk. I am not sure what other information I can provide to help but will add any info if needed.

```
[:error] [pid 28878]  django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[:error]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[:error]  apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[:error] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 81, in populate
[:error] raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[:error] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[:error] mod_wsgi (pid=28878): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/weddingProject/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[:error] mod_wsgi (pid=28878): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/weddingProject/wsgi.py'.
[:error] Traceback (most recent call last):
[:error] File "/opt/python/current/app/weddingProject/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[:error]  application = get_wsgi_application()
[:error] File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
```

I have tried searching for similar errors but no luck.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant#27108924

Comment: And is that the full error trace or is there something before? Often this error will be thrown when the server is trying to restart the process after another error that occurred just before.

Comment: I copied it from the first line all the way down to where it repeats. I am confused by this error.

Comment: Are you sure it repeats exactly the same?

Comment: yes it repeats the same. Just cannot figure out how to fix this.