# What could be the cause when the API populates in Console but fails to populate in frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django

[image]I am new to react and have tried to following various tutorials however i am stuck at this point and just sure something silly is just the cause. I can't get the data to display in frontend. My API works fine on Postman and is Django Rest Framework- made. The data populates to console. Below is the code 1.Note.js 2. App published Notes 3. App.js 4. Note Model :

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Box, Flex } from '@chakra-ui/core';
import NoteDetail from './NoteDetail';

export default function Note({ note }) {
  return (
    <Flex
      align="center"
      justify="flex-end"
      direction="column"
      bg="teal"
      width="300px"
      height="300px"
      borderRadius="40px"
      margin="16px"
      padding="16px"
    >
      <Box as="button" size="144px" bg="white" color="teal" textAlign="center" isTruncated>
        {note.title}
        <Box as="span">{note.display_name}</Box>
        <NoteDetail note={note} key={note.pk} />
      </Box>
    </Flex>
  );
}

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Flex } from '@chakra-ui/core';
import axios from 'axios';
import Error from './Error';
import Loading from './Loading';
import Note from './Note';

export default function AllPublishedNotes() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [isError, setIsError] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const allPublished = async () => {
      setIsError(false);
      setIsLoading(true);
      try {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/api/note/published_notes/');
        setData(result.data);
        console.log(result.data);
      } catch (error) {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setIsError(true);
      }
    };
    allPublished();
  }, []);

  const noData = !data;

  return (
    <>
      <Flex
        justify="center"
        align="center"
        flexWrap="wrap"
        flexDirection={noData ? 'column' : 'row'}
        margin="16px"
        padding="16px"
      >
        {isLoading && !isError ? (
          <Loading />
        ) : isError ? (
          <Error />
        ) : (
          data.map((note) => <Note key={note.pk} note={note} />)
        )}
      </Flex>
    </>
  );
}

import React from 'react';
import { ThemeProvider, CSSReset, theme } from '@chakra-ui/core';
import AllPublishedNotes from './component/AllPublishedNotes';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <CSSReset />
        <AllPublishedNotes />
      </ThemeProvider>
    </>
  );
}
```

```py
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings


class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE )
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Somebody please help look through what the issue could be. Not necessary you use Chakra just need to know what went wrong with my react code itself

Answer (score 0):

by [the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant#answer-55929118) you can debug it by opening `django/apps/registry.py` and around line 80
`raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")`
replace with:
`self.app_configs = {}`

Comment: Tried above but same issue. Still not populating

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the code. Please try the following code.

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/note/published_notes`)
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
      })
```

Comment: Tried above but still not populating to screen. Actually no data was populated on console too

Comment: Try to console console.log(data); You posted a snapshot and assumed on the basis of it.