# Django Deployment with Elastic Beanstalk with AWS: 'Internal Server Error'

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have followed this path in order to deploy an aws application with django in elastic beanstalk:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html
When i go to the site after `eb open`, i get an internal server errror.
Looking at the logs, i think python 2.7 is still in use:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/httpd/access_log
-------------------------------------
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [01/Mar/2021:18:33:45 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [01/Mar/2021:18:33:46 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [01/Mar/2021:18:33:47 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [01/Mar/2021:18:33:49 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 196 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"
127.0.0.1 (-) - - [01/Mar/2021:18:36:05 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 527 "-" "Python-urllib/2.7"

[Mon Mar 01 18:43:06.512243 2021] [:error] [pid 4072] [remote 172.31.21.12:204] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

How can i solve the internal server error?

Comment: As told in the error `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant`, did you check related answers like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55929118/5433925?

Comment: I am on Elastic Beansalk, i cannot just replace something in the environment.