# Can't run Celery task in Django - I either get "AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet" or "RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant"

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I'm trying to setup a task with Celery in Django to run every day at 23:00.

```
app = Celery('App.tasks', broker='redis://localhost')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "App.settings")

django.setup() <== PROBLEM

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(
        crontab(hour=23),
        calc_average_rating.s(),
    )


@app.task
def calc_average_rating(final_content_id):
```

The problem is that in this function, I have `Rating = apps.get_model(app_label='App', model_name='Rating')`, and If I don't call `django.setup()` then I get `django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.`.

However, If I call `django.setup()`, the tasks are running fine but I can't do `manage.py runserver` as I get `RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant`.

Any solutions?

Comment: I'm curious to know what the specific issue is, was it mostly that Celery needed to be given the django app package name instead of the tasks module name?

Comment: I think that the problem was me not starting a `worker` as I thought that only a `beat` is required but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly how to reproduce the environment you're in, so here are some observations from my environment, I hope they help

The only place I have a `Celery()` object is in a standalone file, kept within the "manage.py startproject" generated package,

I think the way I layout a django app is unusual compared to most django users, so to describe it:

```
# .git/  # top folder is my vcs
# setup.py  # packaging for exampleapp
# env/  # python venv created to this service
# exampleapp/  # package generated from startapp
# exampleapp/tasks.py  # package generated from startapp
# exampleproject/  # folder generated from startproject
# exampleproject/exampleproject/  # package generated by startproject
# exampleproject/exampleproject/settings.py  # generated
# exampleproject/exampleproject/celery.py  # created based on celery docs
```

```py
# exampleproject/exampleproject/celery.py
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'exampleproject.settings')

app = Celery('exampleproject')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {self.request!r}'.format(self=self))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.start()
```

and I start the celery jobs like as follows, where my python virtual env folder 'env' is a sibling of the generated exampleproject package

```sh
(
        cd exampleproject
        ../env/bin/python3 -m celery -A exampleproject  worker -l INFO
        # or 
        ../env/bin/python3 -m celery -A exampleproject  beat -l INFO --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler

)
# and for django
./env/bin/python3 exampleproject/manage.py runserver
```

maybe of interest as well

```py
# exampleapp/tasks.py
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y):
    return x+y
```

```py
# exampleproject/exampleproject/settings.py
# suffixed to end of generated file

INSTALLED_APPS.extend([
    'django_celery_results',
    'django_celery_beat',
])

CELERY_TASK_TRACK_STARTED = True
CELERY_TASK_TIME_LIMIT = 30 * 60
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
```

With these parts, I haven't noticed any issues loading the entry points