# Can't host my django website on shared hosting

Tags: python, django

I am trying to deploy my django project on shared hosting. I am trying from couple of hours but still now I can't host my django website and getting "Internal Server Error Error 500".

this is my root **passenger_wsgi.py**

```
from my_root_folder_name.wsgi import application
```

**#setting.py**

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com','www.mydomain.com']
```

I also installed python app and django on my server. Now I am hopeless. I am trying from last five hours for host an website but still now I can't. Where I am doing mistake???

I am seeing those error from error log:

```
  File "/home/sellvqed/virtualenvass/dfdf/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django stops working with RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27093746/django-stops-working-with-runtimeerror-populate-isnt-reentrant)

Comment: blazej no..I saw this questing before post my question

Comment: You saw it but have you tried to use somehow one of those answers?

Comment: blazej I tried but did't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved my problems after delete all apps and virtual folder from my hosting account. T